# How to count the record event_type wise in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In the below sample response, I have 4 `hits` and one user is coming twice with a different `event_type`. I want to count the last data of unique `user_id` with `event_type` wise.

```json
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "index_test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "0yVSN4YBbqa8KnE1E9FS",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "event_type": "1",
        "user_id": "11777"
        "event_date": "2023-02-20 07:24:28"
      },
      "sort": [1675965370212]
    },
    {
      "_index": "index_test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "mXpSN4YBLFzGpeA-E4VI",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "event_type": "1",
        "user_id": "11677"
        "event_date": "2023-02-20 08:15:28"
      },
      "sort": [1675965370207]
    },
    {
      "_index": "index_test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "mnpSN4YBLFzGpeA-E4VM",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "event_type": "2",
        "user_id": "11777"
        "event_date": "2023-02-20 08:22:28"
      },
      "sort": [1675965370210]
    },
    {
      "_index": "index_test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "mHpSN4YBLFzGpeA-E4VD",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "event_type": "7",
        "user_id": "11293"
        "event_date": "2023-02-20 08:27:28"
      },
      "sort": [1675965370202]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with top_hits it is coming with the last user data. But there are some problems here top_hits length is 10000 and my data are more than 50 thousand. So all results are not coming.

2nd I want to only the count data with event_type wise. So, not required for data. Please help me with how can I do it with the Elasticsearch query.

In the above result, I want to output like:

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "last_activities": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "unique_user": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "unique_user": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 7,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "unique_user": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*In `event_type : 1` field there are two records but the user_id `11777` whose last `event_type` is `2` So it will not count in my aggregations*

**Aggregations Query:**

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "last_activities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
              "user_id",
              "event_type"
            ],
            "sort": {
              "created_date": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your aggregation query?

Comment: @MusabDogan Updated my question. Please check the aggregation query

Comment: I recommend you to use transform. https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-use-transforms-to-track-your-most-recent-customer-orders

Comment: Quick question: why do you have `unique_user: 1` for `key: 1`? There are obviously two different unique users with event type 1

Comment: @Val Because If a user has more than one event then we should fetch only one which is last inserted in the elasticsearch.

Comment: Oh, ok got it, thanks for the clarification. There's no date, though, so does that mean that the higher the event type sequence number, the more recent the event is?

Comment: @Val yes I have event_date (not mentioned in my question).

Comment: @Val I have updated the question and added `event_date` please check.

Comment: so you want something like "select count(distinct user_id) group by event_type"? i'm not sure this is possible in ES with one aggregation.

Comment: @TomElias Yes,  Here is the query for SQL. I want to same as elasticsearch `SELECT MAX(id) AS MAXID, user_id FROM user_events GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAXID DESC;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be implemented with regular aggregations, but can be done using the [`script_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) which allows you to implement your own logic. Here is my shot at it. The code is partly commented, but should be straightforward.

```
POST test-events/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "last_activities": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.docs = []",
        "map_script": "state.docs.add(new HashMap(params['_source']))",
        "combine_script": "return state.docs",
        "reduce_script": """
          def users = new HashMap(); 
          def eventTypes = new HashMap();

          for (state in states) { 
            for (d in state) { 
              def eventKey = d.event_type.toString();
              // 1. check if the event type has not been seen yet
              if (!eventTypes.containsKey(eventKey)) {
                // new event type bucket
                eventTypes[eventKey] = [
                  'key': d.event_type,
                  'docCount': 1,
                  'users': new HashSet(),
                  'uniqueUsers': 1
                ];
              } else {
                eventTypes[eventKey].docCount++;
              }
              
              // 2a. check if the user has not been seen yet
              if (!users.containsKey(d.user_id)) {
                users[d.user_id] = new HashMap(d);
              }
              // 2b. otherwise check if the event type is more recent
              else {
                if (users[d.user_id].event_type < d.event_type) {
                  def docCount = users[d.user_id].docCount;
                  users[d.user_id] = d;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          
          // add the unique user count
          users.values().stream().forEach(user -> {
            def eventKey = user.event_type.toString();
            eventTypes[eventKey].users.add(user.user_id);
            eventTypes[eventKey].uniqueUsers = eventTypes[eventKey].users.size();
          });

          eventTypes.keySet().stream().forEach(eventKey -> {
            eventTypes[eventKey].remove('users');
          });
          
          return eventTypes;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result you'd get by running this would be as you expect:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "last_activities" : {
      "value" : {
        "1" : {
          "key" : "1",
          "docCount" : 2,
          "uniqueUsers" : 1
        },
        "2" : {
          "key" : "2",
          "docCount" : 1,
          "uniqueUsers" : 1
        },
        "7" : {
          "key" : "7",
          "docCount" : 1,
          "uniqueUsers" : 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got error. Please check the error screenshot https://ibb.co/6m1LSWK

Comment: I fixed the code, please try again

Comment: I got another error. Please check https://ibb.co/BPXZ9zq

Comment: Can you show me a **real** document, because what you are showing in the question is obviously not the exact documents you have (type wise, i.e. string vs integer values)

Comment: Please find the query and result: https://file.io/9KJ8qX930gKd

Comment: Impossible to connect to that site

Comment: Can we connect through meet? I will show you the exact query and response

Comment: Just take a picture, it should be enough

Comment: Check the attached screeshot https://ibb.co/6wb8Jw3

Comment: Thanks, `event_type` is an integer not a string, then :-) I've revised my answer accordingly, it should work now

Comment: Yes, It's working now. Let me verify whether the responses are accurate or not. Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have verified and everything is correct. I need a little bit of change in your response. I don't want to show the `users` ids and show only event_type 1,2 and 3 uniqueUsers

Comment: Great, glad it helped! I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :). If the data is more than 10,000  will it gives the correct count or not because elastic search shows a maximum of 10,000 data in a request?

Comment: If you mean more than 10000 documents in your index, then it's going to work like you expect

Comment: I have another help. This question fetches the number of counts in aggregations. Same I need to fetch the data in our hits. :(

Comment: Thanks for accepting and glad I could be of help so far. Let's maybe start a new thread to not cram too much into this one.

Comment: Hi, Still I am getting count issue. Please help me.

Comment: Sure, but please see my previous comment, thanks

Comment: I have added another question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75617935/2330905